# Schrader valve core removed, tyre still not deflating

Tags: honda, tires, civic, donut, schrader-valve

This is the space-saver spare wheel for my Honda Civic mk8 fwiw.

I've unscrewed and removed the Schrader valve core and the tyre is still not deflating at all. The tyre is quite old, possibly 10 years old. What's my best course of action?

Comment: What is your ultimate aim?

Comment: Wondering if someone put some [Slime](https://slime.com/) in it? You might put a thin wire down the valve stem where the core would have been to see if it can "assist" in it deflating.

Comment: Yeah the slime/sealant crossed my mind and I haven't done so but I bought it used so previous owner may well have done. I just wanted to run it by here before poking anything down there. I'll push a straightened paper clip down and see what happens...